# JBoss 7 + Hibernate + Log4j

Tags: hibernate, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

I setup my Java EE 6 application taking as a starting point the log4j quickstart in Jboss 7.1.

My key pom.xml additions are:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Define Log4j dependency and its version -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
...
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Version is 1.2.16.

Now I can do:

> private static final Logger logger =
>   Logger.getLogger(MacchinarioController.class);

and use logger as expected. Good!

I have no log4j.xml nor .properties files.

Now I want Hibernate to print in console all SQL statements being executed, **including parameters values**.

I created this log4j.xml and put it in src/main/resources source folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration>

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="info"/>
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="rolling-file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="Program-Name.log"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1000KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="4"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %l - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="ALL" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value ="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="rolling-file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

But nothing shows up, where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) to exclude the servers version of log4j?

If you're starting an application from scratch I definitely wouldn't choose log4j. I am biased to JBoss Logging, but JBoss Logging, slf4j or logback are far better than log4j.

By default JBoss AS 7 uses JBoss Logging with the JBoss Log Manager. Though really you would/could just use JBoss Logging as it will work with any of log manager.

If you do want to use log4j, don't use the log4j configuration. Add the logger/category to the logging subsystem to see the results you are looking for.

All that said, in the next release of JBoss AS 7 your log4j configuration would be found and would just work for you the way you expect it to. The changes have been pushed to the [upstream](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/commit/6da8615681b86c8cde2cd1d3d84188a67466f07e).